# Reapply odd even styles after a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the middle of making a news page. There are large posts for the most recent post of every month, and there is different styling on every odd/even small post using jQuery to select exclusively by class (large posts are '.blogPostBig' and smaller ones are just '.blogPost') :

```
$(function() {
    $('.blogPost:odd').css({
                        'border-left': '0',
                        'padding-right': '0'
    });
    $('.blogPost:even').css({
                        'border-right': '1px solid #4E4E4E',
                        'padding-left': '0'
    });
});
```

Here is it working how it should:

[image: blog example 1]

However, if there is only one small post before the next large post, which you can see in the example below, the styling using the odd and even is messed up:

[image: blog example 2]

I've looked into using .after(), .prev(), .next(), but they don't seem to help me achieve what I want.

What I would like to know is that if there's a way to reset/apply the odd/even styling for the small posts, AFTER a large post, after every large post.

Thanks in advance.

****EDIT****

The layout is like this:

-big 
-small 
-small 
-loadMore

TURNS INTO

-big 
-small 
-small 
-big 
-small 
-small 
-small 
-big 
-loadMore

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the `.blogPost`/`.blogPostBig` elements are siblings, like this:

```
- big
- small
- small
- small
- big
- small
```

You should be able to use [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) as you iterate over each element:

```
$('.blogPostBig').each(function(){
  smallPosts = $(this).next()   // start with the first small post after this big post
    .nextUntil('.blogPostBig')  // stop when we hit another big post
    .andSelf();                 // add back the first small post
  smallPosts.filter(':odd').css({color: 'red'})
  smallPosts.filter(':even').css({color: 'blue'})
});
```

It's a tad messy but I'm not sure that there's a selector-only way (but I could be wrong).

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/eK2Yt/) for you to check out.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want! One thing I guess I failed to mention was I have a 'load more posts' ('.loadMore') div - which seems to ruin this. I'll update the main post to show what I mean by the layout.

Comment: Alright, I almost fixed my problem. The loadMore functionality was messing with it so I just made it re-run on the loadMore click along with it's own code, and that fixed it. All that's left is the 'border-right' styling still gets applied to the loadMore div.

Comment: Fixed it completely: simply gave 'border: 0 !important' to the loadMore div! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted out! If you end up loading a huge number of posts on the page via the 'load more', I would suggest you try to avoid re-processing the elements that were already processed. But that's probably a premature optimization at this stage in your project.